# watin - Settings.FindByDefaultFactory - doesn't seem to use my custom FindByDefaultFactory

Tags: asp.net, watin, webforms

Based on [this article](http://watinandmore.blogspot.com/2008/12/watin-findbydefault-explained.html), I've written a custom class which implements the Watin.Core.interfaces.IFindByDefaultFactory, but I don't think I'm correctly assigning it to the watin settings, because it is never used.

**Basically, Where/when should I assign to the Settings.FindByDefaultFactory?** I've tried in my test Setup, and the text fixture's constructor, but neither seem to cause my custom class to be used. The tests still run and work, but I have to use the full asp.net ID's.

I'm using Watin 2.0.15.928 in VS2008 from nUnit 2.5.2.9222. I am running visual studio as administrator, and tests run sucessfully as long as I don't rely on my custom find logic.

Here's what the start of my text fixture looks like, where I set the FindByDefaultFactory

```
namespace Fundsmith.Web.Main.BrowserTests
{
    [TestFixture]
    class WatinHomepageTests
    {
        private IE _ie;
        [SetUp]
        public void Setup()
        {
            Settings.FindByDefaultFactory = new FindByAspIdFactory();
            _ie = new IE("http://localhost/somepage.aspx");
        }
//etc etc...
```

And this is what my custom Find By Default factory looks like (simplified), unfortunately, it's never called.

```
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;
using WatiN.Core;
using WatiN.Core.Constraints;
using WatiN.Core.Interfaces;

namespace Fundsmith.Web.Main.BrowserTests
{
    public class FindByAspIdFactory : IFindByDefaultFactory
    {
        public Constraint ByDefault(string value)
        {
// This code is never called :(

// My custom find by id code to cope with asp.net webforms ids...
            return Find.ById(value);
        }

        public Constraint ByDefault(Regex value)
        {
            return Find.ById(value);
        }
    }
}
```

Edit: Extra information after the fact.

Based on me fuguring this out, (see answer below), It turns out that the way I was consuming Watin to find the elements was wrong. I was explicitly calling Find.ById, rather than letting the default action occur. So I'd reassigned the default but was then failing to use it!

```
[Test]
public void StepOneFromHomepageShouldRedirectToStepTwo()
{
    _ie.TextField(Find.ById("textBoxId")).TypeText("100");
        //Other test stuff...
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Right, I've figured this one out, and it was me being an idiot and explicitly calling the Find.ById method, rather than letting the default action occur. It seems the test setup is a fine place to set the FindByDefaultFactory.

ie, I was doing this (wrong):

```
    [Test]
    public void StepOneFromHomepageShouldRedirectToStepTwo()
    {
        _ie.TextField(Find.ById("textBoxId")).TypeText("100");
            //Other test stuff...
    }
```

When I should have been simply doing this. (Without the explicit "Find.ById")

```
    [Test]
    public void StepOneFromHomepageShouldRedirectToStepTwo()
    {
        _ie.TextField("textBoxId").TypeText("100");
            //Other test stuff...
    }
```

Not only was this me being stupid, but I didn't include this in my original question, so it would have been impossible for anyone else to figure it out for certain. Double slaps for me.